# Better way to validate username & email availability fields

Tags: jquery, oop, javascript-objects

I have a pretty good OOP JS structure in place, but am looking for some help with validating a username and email field. I have it pretty much working but I think the username and email could be validated better.

I have setup a delegate on a group of fields(elements) and then I perform validation on these. My code validation for username and email fields looks like:

```
} else if( regExpTest === "AjaxCall") {

if(currentValue.length > 0){

    availability = ZEN.checkAvailability( $this ); //Check weather form input value is available in DB

    availability.success(function (data) {

        if(data == "1" && currentField == 'username'){

            $('#usernameErrorExists').fadeIn();
        }

        if(data == "0" && currentField == 'username'){

            $('#usernameErrorExists').fadeOut();

        }

        if(data == "1" && currentField == 'email'){

            $('#emailErrorExists').fadeIn();

        }

        if(data == "0" && currentField == 'email'){

            $('#emailErrorExists').fadeOut();

        }

    });

    isValid = true;

}
```

}

The ZEN.checkAvailability function looks like:

```
ZEN.checkAvailability = function( input ) {

// get input name
var inputName = input.attr('name')

// get value
var inputValue = input.val();

return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/"+ inputName +"-check",
    data: inputName +'='+ inputValue,
    cache: false
});

};
```

My question is, is there a better way to validate the returned response from the AJAX request?

Thanks
Robert

Comment: you can fadeout the error when the user starts editing the field, that would save you the "if" case for checking if there is no error. and it would be better usability in my opinion

Comment: Yeah, thats the way I ended up doing it eventually, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working better by altering the jQuery fades to a more appropriate time on the error messages.

Thanks to Chao for their comments.